# Passing multiple targets to a subant

Tags: android, ant, build

I have an Android project built with Ant using some standard targets (debug, release, install, clean, etc). I've found that I can run multiple targets with a command like:

```
ant clean debug
```

which in this case would run "clean" followed by "debug" build on the project. This works fine.

I also have another project built with Ant on which my first master project depends. I'm trying to automatically build the subproject in the prebuild step. So far I have this:

```
<target name="-pre-build">        
    <subant target="${ant.project.invoked-targets}" failonerror="true">
        <fileset dir="../other_project" includes="build.xml" />
    </subant>

    <!-- (additional steps here) -->
</target>
```

This works for one target (e.g. `ant debug`) but when I run multiple targets (e.g. `ant clean debug`) I get the following error:

```
Target "clean,debug" does not exist in the project "com.foo.other_project"
```

Clearly `invoked-targets` is a comma-separated list when I really want to re-run subant for each of the targest. Does anyone know how to achieve this? Is there a way to pass a list of targets to subant, or perhaps iterate through the list and run subant once per target?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html) describes how to specify multiple targets:

> You can specify multiple targets using nested "target" elements instead of using the "target" attribute. These will be executed as if Ant had been invoked with a single target whose dependencies are the targets so specified, in the order specified.

An example is also provided:

```
<subant failonerror="false">
    <fileset dir="." includes="**/build.xml" excludes="build.xml"/>
    <target name="clean"/>
    <target name="build"/>
</subant>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response; this works for hardcoded values but `<target name="${ant.project.invoked-targets}"/>` still fails with the same error (target "clean,debug" does not exist). Is there a way to split apart the comma-separated value and dynamically simulate multiple `<target>` nodes?

Comment: @Alan You have misunderstood the error message. You cannot submit a comma separated list as the name of the target and expect it to iterate through that list. That is what the multiple "target" elements in the "subant" task allow you to do. Yes, it is possible to use ant-contrib "for" task to iterate through a comma separated list, but this requires an additional jar to be added to your project (Not part of standard ANT).

Comment: I'm still unclear how to get multiple "target" elements without hardcoding the target names. "clean,debug" was just an example, I'd want it to work regardless of the target(s) invoked. I've heard ant is dependency-oriented, so with that thinking the issue is: any target (e.g. "clean", "debug", "foo") in master_project depends on a target with the same name in other_project.